# PHP Header Location Doesn't work - Mobile Redirection Script in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I found this code on various sits on the internet but i somehow can't bring it to work..

```
<?php
header("Location: http://hdwbin.com/cute-brown-cat.html");
exit;
?>
```

I uploaded this code as test.php to 2 different hosts and both won't redirect.
On the second host i edited the header.php file from Wordpress theme so there is no other Code displayed to the client before the Header happens.

1 Host:
Returns nothing as result.

2 Host:
502 Bad Gateway
The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.

Any ideas or suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: header will only work when there is no text printed on screen before it. because headers are sent when page load starts.

Comment: I use javascript to redirect instead of php like this: `<script>window.location='http://hdwbin.com/cute-brown-cat.html';</script>`

Comment: @madforstrength that's incorrect, as headers are sent as the response from the server, has nothing to do with the content.

This code should work btw, I've copy pasted and ran it.

I suggest you put the code in some clean empty test.php file and run that file directly, wordpress might be doing evil stuff

Answer (score 1):

Your vanilla code does work on my hosting. If you are placing this in WordPress theme header.php chances are some headers had already been sent and modifying headers at this point won't work.

Answer (score 1):

It is error related in "header already sent". I think ob_flush() will fix this issue. Please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<?php
die(header("Location: http://hdwbin.com/cute-brown-cat.html");
?>
```

this code directly redirects to the URL without returning any data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't really want this in the header to be processed on every request.

Use the WordPress [wp_redirect()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) function to perform redirects. It handles some extra checks for sanitization and IIS compatibility.

Perform your redirect in the [`init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) hook which runs before any headers are sent:

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    wp_redirect( 'http://hdwbin.com/cute-brown-cat.html', 301 );
    exit;
} );
```